# How to enable components page in Apache Felix Web console

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, declarative-services

I would like to deploy Apache Felix Web Console for research purpose.
According to the Apache Felix doc, there are the page to control components(OSGI services).
However, after starting the web console on localhost port 8080, I can not access components page through this URL: `localhost:8080/system/console/components`

[image]

I also install an start DS Plugin for Web Console but It seem not work. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use SCR (Declarative Services) (download from this https://felix.apache.org/downloads.cgi) instead of org.osgi.service.components